# Predict response vs manual for logistic regression probability

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to manually calculate the probability of a given x with logistic regression model.

my model looks like this **fit2 <- glm(ability~stability, data = df2)**

I created a function that gives me the response:

```r
estimator <- function(x){
  predict(fit2, type = "response", newdata = data.frame(stability=x))
}
```

this function gives me 0.5304603 for the value x=550

then i create the manual version. For this i use the function `p = e^(B0+B1*x)/(1 + e^(B0+B1*x))`

so our code will look like this

```r
est <- function(par, x){
  x = c(1,x)
  exp(par%*%x)/(1+exp(par%*%x))
}
```

where par = fit2$coefficients, x = 550

but this code returns 0.6295905

Why?

edit:

```
summary(fit2):
Call:
glm(formula = ability ~ stability, data = df2)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-0.78165  -0.33738   0.09462   0.31582   0.72823  

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept) -1.531574   0.677545   -2.26  0.03275 * 
stability    0.003749   0.001229    3.05  0.00535 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 0.1965073)

    Null deviance: 6.7407  on 26  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 4.9127  on 25  degrees of freedom
AIC: 36.614

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2
```

Comment: We need to see the contents of `fit2` if  we are going to help you.  Not just the coefficients, but all of it.

Comment: is summary enough?

Comment: You've not fitted a logistic regression: `(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 0.1965073)`.  It looks like you've omitted `family="binomial"` from your `glm` call.  I'd expect to see `(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)`.